# Как сравнить даты?

Tags: java, android

Везде посмотрел, пишут про `before()`, `after()`, `compareTo()`. Но проблема в том что у меня две кнопки и один только календарь.

**Вот клики двух кнопок:**

```
public void initButtonListeners(final Date today, final Calendar nextYear) {
    findViewById(id.linearCalendar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCalendarInDialog("Выберите дату выезда", R.layout.calendar_dialog_customized);

            if (departData == null) {
                dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(new Date());
            }
            else {
                dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(new Date(departData));
            }

            isFrom = true;
        }
    });

    findViewById(id.linearArrive).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCalendarInDialog("Выберите дату приезда", R.layout.calendar_dialog_customized);

            if (arriveData == null){
                dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(new Date());
            } else {
                dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(new Date(arriveData));
            }

            isFrom = false;
        }
    });

}
```

**Клик на дату:**

```
dialogView.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        DateFormat dayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(Date date) {

            if(isFrom){
                departData = dateFormat.format(date);
                departdOw = dayOfWeek.format(date);

                tvDepart.setText(departData);
                tvSubDepart.setText(departdOw);
            }else{
                arriveData = dateFormat.format(date);
                arrivedOw = dayOfWeek.format(date);

                tvArrive.setText(arriveData);
                tvSubArrive.setText(arrivedOw);
            }

            theDialog.dismiss();

        }

    });
```

Мне нужно вывести Тост, если выбрали дату приезда которая меньше даты выезда.
И пытался сравнить `departDate` с `arriveDate`... Но ошибка, потому они `String` типа. а кроме него нечего сравнивать.

**Вопрос:**

Как быть в этом случае, как сравнить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Преобразуйте `departDate` и `arriveDate` типа `String` в тип `Date`, а затем сравнивайте.

Пример преобразования:

```
String departDate = "Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(departDate);
```

Comment: У меня форматирование идет в таком виде, так пойдет или нужно именно как у вас форматировку использовать?

Comment: @Omuradil, в примере формат даты `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"` используется для строки `"Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984"`. Вам нужно использовать такой формат, в котором представлены ваши строковые поля `departDate` и `arriveDate`.

Comment: спасибо, попробую...

Answer (score 4):

Даты можно сравнивать с помощью `getTime()`. Например:

```
...............................
    Date date1 = new Date(arg1);
    Date date2 = new Date(arg2);
```

Собственно, сам пример сравнения:

```
boolean b;
if (date1.getTime() > date2.getTime())
 b = true;
 else b = false;
System.out.println(b);
```